# Checking for usernames in two lists

Tags: python-3.x, list

Sorry if this question comes off as simple, but brand new to coding and starting off with Python. The objective of the code below was to make two lists and to loop through the New Users list and to check if any of them match with the current_users list, yet I made one match but it still wont come through with the given print in the if loop. It will print that they are all unique, even though they arent.

```
new_user = ['roblew', 'keek', 'huh', 'lucas', 'xd']
current_user = ['roblew', 'adam', 'josh', 'alex', 'kiana']

for new_users in new_user:
    if new_users == current_user:
        print("Sorry " + new_users + " that username is taken")
    else:
        print("The username " + new_users + " is available!")
```

Thanks!

Comment: change `new_users` to `new_user` and vice versa. Assuming `new_users` having list of users.

Comment: Please note that Python needs correct indentation - please be sure that you haven't lost spaces in the process of posting. Next, the `for` loop is unnecessary as `if current_user in new_user:` tests if `current_user` is in the `new_user` list. However, your naming seems a little wonky, though, so we'd need to see how the lists are built - `if new_user in current_users:` reads much better!

Comment: Please be very conscious about indentation when pasting into questions, especially with Python. You can just paste your code, then select all of it and hit Ctrl-K (or Cmd-K on Mac). In this cased, Iagom changed your code in the only way possible for it not to be an error, but sometimes it is not possible to deduce what the poster meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two lists, the easiest (and fastest!) way to see if there are any common elements is to convert them to sets and use the intersection operator:

```
new_users = ['roblew', 'keek', 'huh', 'lucas', 'xd']
current_users = ['roblew', 'adam', 'josh', 'alex', 'kiana']

set(new_users) & set(current_users)
# => {'roblew'}
```

(I also took the liberty of changing the variable names to plural, to better reflect their contents.)

To check whether a single element is in a list, you can use `in` operator as mentioned in comments; this is a bit slower though, as `in` checks each element to see if it's the one. So you could also do it like this, which is similar to your code:

```
for new_user in new_users:
    if new_user in current_users:             # note `in` instead of `==`!
        print("Sorry " + new_user + " that username is taken")
    else:
        print("The username " + new_user + " is available!")
```

You can also use `==` to manually do what `in` did, by checking each element against each element:

```
for new_user in new_users:
    for current_user in current_users:
        if new_user == current_user:
            print("Sorry " + new_user + " that username is taken")
            break
    else:
        print("Sorry " + new_user + " that username is taken")
```

Here, I use the `for ... else` syntax that is pretty unique to Python, where `else` will execute only if I didn't `break` the loop.